# Show embedded pdf file in winforms C#

Tags: c#, pdf

I'm trying to show a pdf file in my form.

I used this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a59LvC6BOuk

But nothing happens , It opens a new inaccessible blank Adobe Acrobat window.

This is my code :

```
  OpenFileDialog op1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (op1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pdfRead.src = op1.FileName;
        }
```

What can i do to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has done as you asked. most likely - although from the code provided, its hard to tell..

However you could try, putting a panel where you want your pdf to show - assume its called panel1.

You need this in your form

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
```

and to change your code si it runs a process of that pdf to suck it into your app

```
if (op1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    Process p = Process.Start("op1.FileName");
    Thread.Sleep(500); // Allow the process to open it's window
    SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);
}
```

This code is not perfect - it doesnt allow for many things.. such as you should maybe hide the panel and show it depending on if that pdf process works and terminates.. etc

Comment: i've tried the above and it opened the pdf in a new windows of acrobat reader.

i have an example of how i want it to appear:
http://image.prntscr.com/image/888dace6a5ff4729828c0c5b8043b5a8.png

Comment: ok, but Im not on this planet to do it all for you - I use that code to put putty into a tab on a winform app, works like a charm..

Comment: what do you mean when you said that you put putty into a tab ? (Putty is a SSH client , isn't it ) ?

Comment: Yes, but in the same way you should be able to put your pdf viewer in a tab.. the above is commonly used to do exactly that, take some random app, notepad, etc, and stick it in a control in your application.

Comment: the opening in a new window works , however the embedding dosen't.
i wrote the code that you provided and it showed me the pdf in a new  window , for some reason it dosen't embed.

Comment: as I said, try it with something else like notepad  - it maybe your viewer has some nasty code in it that means it wont work..

Comment: i've tried using another application as you suggested, notepad for example. 
the same happens here, 
instead openning in the panel, it opens the notepad in a new window,
and this new window is problamatic, it opens and disappears,
if i'm doing it fast enough i can type few letters into it then it disappears in the thin air of space.
the same exact thing happens if using acrobat reader.

i'll be glad if it's not a hassle if you can show me how is the output looks when your're using the code.
thank you very much sir...

Comment: Im female. http://imgur.com/j7QqEb4.jpg - Im using tabs because I wanted many open at once.

Comment: Sorry , didn't know you're a woman , I don't know why it dosen't working for me.

Comment: it potentially is because you open the file not the app with the file... but you're a coder.. try stuff